# Change jstree Node Icon via Javascript

Tags: jstree

I want to select a specific node from my jstree based on its ID and then change its icon.  I want to do this via javascript, and cannot find a basic example on the jstree documentation.
Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe you want to check the type plugin.

Comment: Thank you.  I used the type plugin, and was able to change the node icon via javascript: $("#" + id).attr("rel", "waiting");

Answer (score 0):

I think jstree does not offer any API for this. I just looked into an older project and i did it this way:

```
$divTree.find("li[data-id=" + id + "] > a > ins.jstree-icon").css("background-image", "url(" + iconUrl + ")");
```

In my case, I identified the node via an attribute `data-id`. If you directly use IDs, you probably have to adjust the selector to something along the lines of `#myId > a > ins.jstree-icon`.

Hope this helps!

EDIT
When selecting the node based on its id, try this:

```
$divTree.find("#" + id + " > a > ins.jstree-icon").css("background-image", "url(" + iconUrl + ")");
```

probably you could also do this (without performance loss, maybe even performance gain?)

```
$"#" + id + " > a > ins.jstree-icon").css("background-image", "url(" + iconUrl + ")");
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, however it didnt work for me.  I'm not getting any errors in firebug either, which makes it more difficult.

Comment: I used $('#TreeviewDiv').find, and also put data-id=#" + NodeId + " - but still no good.

Comment: There must be a better way, maybe not using javascript?

Comment: try changing this `data-id=#" + NodeId + "` to just `#" + NodeId + "`.
basically, the `#` just indicates that your selector should be based on the id-attribute. also, without javascript there is no chance changing the icon without a full page refresh, so this should be the way to go.

Comment: i also updated my answer. in your case it should probably be `NodeId` instead of `id` though.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.
The second solution above seems to work.  The current folder icon of the node disappears.  If i inspect the element via firebug I can see it has changed:
<ins class="jstree-icon" style="background-image: url("throbber.gif");"> </ins>
However visually I cannot see the newly assigned icon on the screen?

Comment: I was able to achieve this via the type plugin.  Thank you for your help.